# TypeError: Cannot read property 'onAfterSave' of undefined

Tags: javascript, database, velo

While creating a website on Wix , I wanted to fetch the wishes from the DB as soon as they were posted. I wrote this code :

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

function getData() {
    let query = wixData.query('Wishes');
    return query.limit(1000).find().then(results => {
        console.log('getData', results);
        return results.items;
    });

}
$w.onReady(() => {
    $w["#wisheswrite"].onAfterSave(() => {
        getData().then((items) => {
            $w["#wisheshere"].data = items;
        });
    });
});
```

But it seems to give error and i am not able to find a proper solution to it so asking it here , please help

Comment: Try normal brackets `$w("#wisheswrite")` instead of `$w["#wisheswrite"]`

Answer (score 0):

You should use round brackets parentheses: $w("#wisheswrite")